# How to create association one to many and many to one between two entities in gorm?

Tags: postgresql, grails, one-to-many

I'm new in Grails. I have a problem with generation association many to one and one to many between two tables. I'm using postgresql database.

Employee.groovy

```
class Employee {

    String firstName
    String lastName
    int hoursLimit
    Contact contact
    Account account
    Unit unit
    char isBoss

    static hasMany = [positionTypes:PositionType, employeePlans: EmployeePlan]
}
```

EmployeePlan.groovy

```
class EmployeePlan {

    AcademicYear academicYear
    HourType hourType
    int hours
    float weightOfSubject
    Employee employee

    static belongsTo = [SubjectPlan]
}
```

I'd like to have access from employee to list of employeePlans and access from EmployeePlan to Employee instance. Unfortunately GORM generates only two tables Employee and EmployeePlan with employee_id. I don't have third table which should have two columns employee_id and employee_plan_id. Could you help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your setup is correct, as you write from Employee class you can access to a collection of EmployeePlan (take care, that if you don't explicitly define EmployeePlan like a List, it will be a Set by default)  and from EmployeePlan you can access Employee. 
If you need List, you can define it like that:

```
class Employee {

String firstName
String lastName
int hoursLimit
Contact contact
Account account
Unit unit
char isBoss
//explicitly define List
List<EmployeePlan> employeePlans

static hasMany = [positionTypes:PositionType, employeePlans: EmployeePlan]
}
```

But back to your question. You'd like to have join table between Employee and employeePlan, but why? Its not necessary, since you have bidirectional mapping with sets (unordered), grails will not create a join table. Can you explain why do you need it? In grails the references will be auto-populated, so I don't see any issue here.
If need to preserve order of employeePlans, then define it as List, shown above, and grails will create a join table with corresponding indexes.

Comment: ok you have right it will not create join table, but I don't understand where is storage data about which EmployeePlan belongs to Employee?

Comment: Yes, it will create join table, but now I don't have employee_id in employee_plan table.. When i remove `Employee employee` from EmployeePlan.groovy it will create join table but when I added it, I have only employee_id in EmployeePlan.. I don't know why..

Comment: I think you need to realize, that for bidirectional mapping you actually don't need references on both side. Imagine both cases: 1) We have employee (id: 666), and we need to find all his plans "select * from employee_plan p where p.employee_id = 666". 2) we have a plan (id:123) and need to find which employee it belongs: "select * from employee_plan p inner join employee e on p.employee_id = e.id where p.id = 123". You have ability to find both sides with one mapping column...

Comment: As a response to your second question, read some articles how to handle associations in database models. In general, when you have join table between employee and employee_plan, you will not have foreign key reference from employee_plan anymore. Because the join table replaces that.

Comment: Thanks barti for your help. I think that I understood it.

Answer (score 0):

have you read the [ref-doc](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.x/guide/GORM.html#tableAndColumnNames)? it gives you the answer immediately:

```
class Person {
  String firstName

  static hasMany = [addresses: Address]

  static mapping = {
    table 'people'
    firstName column: 'First_Name'
    addresses joinTable: [name: 'Person_Addresses',
                          key: 'Person_Id',
                          column: 'Address_Id']
  }
}
```

Comment: maybe you don't have the permissions for schema changes... you can also create the join table manually